# How to change original CSS when asp validator isn't valid

Tags: css, asp.net

Hi I am trying to change my CSS when the validators are not valid. I tried alot of things like changing it with CssClass in my validator, use javascript to change it or even with C# in the backend of the program. But it does not seems to work.

This is the CSS style and the part that has 3 * around it causes the color change of the text and buttom border

```
<style type="text/css">
.inlog {
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.inlog .invoertext {
  display:block;
  ***color: white;***
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-34px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-34px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-34px);
  transform: translateY(-34px);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.inlog .invoertype {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  ***border-bottom: 2px solid white;***
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 200px;
}
.inlog .invoertype:focus {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 400px;
}
.inlog .invoertype:focus + .invoertext {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 13px;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-74px);
  transform: translateY(-74px);
}
.inlog .invoertype:valid + .invoertext {
  font-size: 13px;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-74px);
  transform: translateY(-74px);
}
</style>
```

This are my validators and textbox

```
<label id="Signin" class="Loginform">

    <label class="inlog">
        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtNaam" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Voornaam"></asp:Label>
    </label>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        CssClass="Errormsg"
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtNaam"
        ErrorMessage="Naam is required"
        ForeColor="Red"
        ValidationGroup="Sigin">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
        CssClass="Errormsg"
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtNaam"
        ErrorMessage="Voer geldige voornaam in"
        ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
        ForeColor="Red"
        ValidationGroup="Sigin">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    <label class="inlog">
        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtemailsignin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
    </label>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        class="Errormsg"
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtemailsignin"
        ErrorMessage="Email is required"
        ForeColor="Red"
        ValidationGroup="Sigin">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
        ID="Errormsgid"
        class="Errormsg"
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtemailsignin"
        ErrorMessage="Voer geldig email adress in"
        ValidationExpression="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,6})+$"
        ForeColor="Red"
        ValidationGroup="Sigin">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    <asp:CustomValidator
        ID="Signinemailgebuik"
        class="Errormsg"
        runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Email is al in gebruik"
        ForeColor="Red"
        ValidationGroup="Sigin">

    </asp:CustomValidator>


    <label class="inlog">
        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtPasswordsignin" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
    </label>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
        class="Errormsg"
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtPasswordsignin"
        ErrorMessage="Password is required"
        ForeColor="Red"
        ValidationGroup="Sigin">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
        class="Errormsg"
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtPasswordsignin"
        ErrorMessage="Password does not meet requirements"
        ValidationExpression="^.*(?=.{6,})((?=.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]){1})(?=.*\d)((?=.*[a-z]){1})((?=.*[A-Z]){1}).*$"
        ForeColor="Red"
        ValidationGroup="Sigin">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    <label class="inlog">
        <asp:TextBox class="invoertype" ID="txtpasswordsignrepeat" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label class="invoertext" runat="server" Text="Repeat password">
        </asp:Label>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            class="Errormsg"
            runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtpasswordsignrepeat"
            ErrorMessage="Password is required"
            ValidationGroup="Sigin"
            ForeColor="Red">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:CompareValidator
            class="Errormsg"
            runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtpasswordsignrepeat"
            ControlToCompare="txtPasswordsignin"
            Type="String" Operator="Equal"
            ErrorMessage="Password not the same"
            ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationGroup="Sigin"> 
        </asp:CompareValidator>

    </label>

    <label class="buttonplacement">
        <asp:Button ValidationGroup="Sigin" class="btn-draw" runat="server" Text="Sign in" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" />
    </label>
</label>
```

You see some diffrent with class and CSSClass in the validators that because I tried diffrent options if that would make a diffrence but all options doesn't seem to work.

The higligted parts in the image are the items that are changed with the color inside the Css and those I want to be red if the validator is not valid.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqjAk.png)

Thanks in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/L3cab2hd/

This is the best I can do but it doesn't seem to work and look the same

Comment: Can you please create fiddle or snippet?, So we can trying to help you.

Comment: @jaydeeppatel yea sure wait a minute please

Comment: Eddited in but it doesn't look or work the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following snippet. It will check all Validators on the page and add or remove a CSS class based on the validity.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ValidatorUpdateIsValid = function () {
            Page_IsValid = AllValidatorsValid(Page_Validators);
            checkValidators();
        }
    });

    function checkValidators() {
        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            var inputControl = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
            if (null != inputControl) {
                WebForm_RemoveClassName(inputControl, "validation-summary-errors");
                $("#" + inputControl.id).closest("label").removeClass("validation-summary-errors-label");
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            inputControl = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
            if (null != inputControl && !Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                WebForm_AppendToClassName(inputControl, "validation-summary-errors");
                $("#" + inputControl.id).closest("label").addClass("validation-summary-errors-label");
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .validation-summary-errors {
        border: 3px solid #ff0000 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It does work on my other page! Thank I will find the rest out !

Comment: Check if you have my latest snippet. I had to modify it slightly to get it to work with textboxes that had the class attribute already. I tested it and it works.

Comment: one other question how could I get the text red aslo?

Comment: Set the color property in the `validation-summary-errors` css: `color: red;`

Comment: Tried that but that does not seems the work even with !important behind it text color stays the same altough the border does work

Comment: It is working here... That probably means that some css is overriding the color....

Comment: It did work on the text that I am writing but I think I didn't explain it good enough I ment the text "Email" and "Password" the thinks that hover above the textbox

Comment: Use jquery to find the closest label and add/remove a class from that: `$("#" + inputControl.id).closest("label").addClass("validation-summary-errors-label");`

Comment: Perhaps stupid question but I am not well known with javascript. So where do I have to insert in? Thanks again for your help and effort

Comment: It is in the answer above.

Comment: It does not seems to work I tried to make new class css with ''validation-summary-errors-label'' Name and "Color:red !important" in it. This did not work. I tried as a other option add "Color:red !important" in "validation-summary-errors" but this doesn't work as well